# Simple form - undefined local variable or method `object'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm getting an error when I try to upload pictures. I've been using twitter-bootstrap gem to format my form view files and it changes the file to a simple_format styling. However, I get an error that gives me a nill class. I've posted the repository below on Github under views > post > _forms.

```
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007ffe08098798>:0x007ffe07536788>
Did you mean?  object_id
```

https://github.com/ArthurTruong5/Instagram_01

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Your `error_span` code is throwing error. What are you trying to achieve by `@post[:image]` etc

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace here?